# Draw a transparent image into a BufferedImage

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to transfer one Image in some other color format (such as `TYPE_INT_ABGR`) into a BufferedImage with `TYPE_INT_ARGB`. There is nothing else in the BufferedImage. Here's how I do it now:

```
BufferedImage argbImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
argbImage.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);
```

The problem is that the pixels of my source image are not transferred if the alpha channel is 0. This is what I expect because the Javadocs for `drawImage()` state that transparent pixels from the source will not affect destination pixels.

I want all my pixels to be transferred to the new image, preserving all four color channels exactly. Is there a different method I can use, or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: What is the underlying reason for your question?

Comment: And do you have a sample image?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm adding an option to respect alpha when comparing images in a Texture packing tool for a game engine. The buffered image is passed into a hashing function. I don't want to modify the rest of the algorithm (or my simple PR will likely be rejected for being too invasive). I just need to get my source image into this BufferedImage without it ignoring the pixels that have zero in the alpha channel.